# Can maven change package declarations when compiling a project?

Tags: java, maven

Well, I have googled this topic many times and I haven't found an answer yet: Can maven change the package declarations right before compiling a project?

My objective is have project A, which is an API, all in one package, and each project B and C will use the same dependency on eclipse. My objective is that once maven is about to compile the project, the package declarations get changed to that project's specific package and then it compiles the project.

This is useful because I have many projects using the same API and I keep making changes to the API itself to suit my needs, but it's a pain to have to go trough every project and change it all again.

If you have any idea how to do this, and, more importantly, if it is possible, let me know please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be possible, but it's not what Maven is for...
Not throwing stones here, but if you're having to change package declarations in your class files every time you make a code change, you have either mis-structured your code, or haven't been using your IDE's refactoring tools to their full potential.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that that's not what Maven is for. But there's always the possibility that there's a plugin that does it; because of the plugins, Maven is a very modular system and can suit many java developers around the world. :P

Edit: The refactoring tools are a great option yes, but they don't work trough projects, as far as I know. And still, it's much better to do it all automatically than one thing at a time.

Comment: You are correct about this, and it is the reason that I framed my answer the way I did, as opposed to just saying "no". I've seen (and used) plugins that sort of abuse the way Maven is supposed to be used, but I generally don't encourage others to do the same. All that said, I've never personally heard of a plugin that can do this, but, then, I've never looked for one either.

Comment: Still, usually everything that gets created is not made to be abused but it ends up being abused. Things like this I don't mind abusing, but making viruses and other malicious things out of this I refuse doing. This type of thing I want to do is just for convenience and saving me the hassle of having to do go trough each of the 20 projects that I have that use the API and pasting the new package and changing the package to that project's specific package. By the way, I just want to change the package because these projects will be running at the same time, and there might be interference.

Comment: What IDE are you using? In Eclipse all refactoring in Maven dependencies work throughout different projects. I usually work with 10+ interdependent projects and changes in an API reflects in all projects.

Answer (score 0):

Google's maven replacer plugin can do such things, it can edit your java files at build time. I have used it for silencing warnings in automatically generated java files. It can definitely be used for even more evil things.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>replace</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>src/main/java/mycodegen/**/*.java</include>
            </includes>
            <regex>true</regex>
            <regexFlags>
                <regexFlag>MULTILINE</regexFlag>
            </regexFlags>
            <replacements>
                <replacement>
                    <token>^public class</token>
                    <value>@SuppressWarnings("all") public class</value>
                </replacement>
            </replacements>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This is what I had used. It should be very similar to change package declarations in Java files. By now there should be much newer versions of the plugin.